# angularjs how to ng-repeat array values as column headings

Tags: angularjs, arrays, firebase-realtime-database, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to **ng-repeat** the values of the below array as the column headings for my **ng-table**?

I am trying to display the value from `$scope.cols` array as the column headings of my table, in other words as the fields, and display all the rows.

[image]

here is my try:

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller as projects">
    <table ng-table-dynamic="projects.tableParams with projects.cols"
           show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
            <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">{{::row[col.field]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is my controller:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', ["$scope", "$filter", "ngTableParams", "DatabaseRef", "$firebaseArray",
function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, DatabaseRef, $firebaseArray) {

    //show all projects

    var showallprojects = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey();
    $scope.allprojectslist = $firebaseArray(showallprojects);
    var data = $scope.allprojectslist;
    data.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.length); // data is loaded here
        $scope.cols = Object.keys(data[0]);
        console.log($scope.cols);
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1, // show first page
            count: 7, // count per page
            sorting: { country: "asc" },
            filter : {
            }
        }, {
            filterSwitch: true,
            total: 0, //data.length, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                // use build-in angular filter
                var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                    $filter('filter')($scope.allprojectslist, params.filter()) :
                    $scope.allprojectslist;             
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :                    
                    $scope.allprojectslist;

                params.total($scope.allprojectslist.length);
                // set total for recalc pagination
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));                
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

### note:

the ngtable dynamic model is taken from [here](https://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/jPxgzY?editors=1010) and the [doc is here](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/src/browser/ngTableDynamic.directive.ts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I've probably misunderstood your question, I thought the code above wasn't a copy of st-table examples.

In your scenario, if you want to display each `$scope.cols` value as a heading you need to `ng-repeat="col in cols"` and print out your current col value `{{col}}`.

I'm assuming your `data` inside the body of the table to be an array of objects, and each object to be in the form of `[col] => value`.

I'm updating the code sample below.

You simply need to structure better your table.

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller as projects">
  <table ng-table-dynamic="projects.tableParams with projects.cols"
       show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
       <th ng-repeat="col in cols">{{col}}</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
      <td ng-repeat="col in col">{{ row[col] || "empty"}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

So basically we're cycling the $columns array once for building the heading of the table; then we cycle the $data array to get an array of objects (I suppose), and each iteration is a new row; then inside of each row we cycle the $columns array again to get the `col.field` we're looking for, and each iteration will be a new `<td>` inside our row.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not working, not because it is wrong, but because I don't have `field` defined anywhere. I have just picked it up from the example on the website above. I don't know if it is inherent to the ng table or it should be defined somewhere. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well, if your data are structured inside an object, they probably are in the format key => value; you can simply extract your keys with `Object.keys()` and store them in an array of `fields`, and then do what I've said above...